# Use of "always" and "am"

Tags: word-order

I was recently talking with someone on internet. I wrote to him:

1. I myself am searching for this.
　 2. "I" in English when used to express myself is capitalized always".

I think my statement would appear weird to native English speakers. The correct sense seem to be:

3. I am searching for this myself.
　 4. "I" in English is always capitalized when used to express myself.

Please do not explain very technically. I want to know how native English speaker would understand my sentences. How the sentence should be written so that it become fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second set of sentences is more colloquial, but the only real error in the first set is the placement of "always". The ordinary locations for *always* are

- **after** *BE* or *HAVE* or the first auxiliary in a verb construction (as in your example), or
- **before** a single verb other than *BE* or *HAVE*.

It is placed at the end of the sentence only as an afterthought, or for extra emphasis, so when it is placed there it must be set off with a comma or dash, reflecting the vocal pause before it is added:

> It is capitalized—*always*.

The other differences between the two sets are not errors, but bear different emphases.

MYSELF

- *Xself* at the end of a sentence is roughly equivalent to *too*; it may express a little more emphasis, or stress personal participation.

  > The King is looking into this himself, *not having a servant look into it*.
- *Xself* set immediately after its referent, *X Xself*, is emphatic: it is roughly the equivalent of *even X*. It is employed when the referent's involvement is surprising or impressive:

  - The King himself is looking into this, *though you might have thought he wasn't interested*.
  - The King himself is looking into this, *which tells you how important we consider the matter*.

When CLAUSE
The placement of *when used to express myself* depends on the context.

- If the most important thing in the sentence is the capitalization, *is always capitalized* should come immediately after the subject, as in your second version. In that case, *when used to express myself* becomes an important but secondary qualification of the general statement
- But if the most important thing is distinguishing **when** 'I' is capitalized, that should come before the predicate, as in your first example, and it should be set off with commas or dashes:

  > 'I' in English, when it expresses myself, is always capitalized.

  In this position it 'interrupts' the ordinary Subject-Predicate order, which gives it extra prominence.

Comment: Sir, I think it would be worth to link the actual conversation. It is in the comments of this [post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/110891/31782). I am user: 31782 and talking to user:45332. I was in fact putting more emphasis on "_always_". I think I communicated well. Did I?  I haven't learned about formatting but I will do soon. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Anupam Your sentence is perfectly clear, and the only 'error' is lack of separation for that "always". Such minor departures from ordinary academic practice are ignored in casual conversation like that.

Comment: Second thanks for your comment. This is  truly an awesome site. Such a good are experts there to help. I didn't expected such a good answer. Infinite thanks.

Comment: "Such a good are experts there to help" sounds awkward, and may not be grammatically correct. You'd probably say "There are such good experts here to help" instead. (I hope this doesn't offend you, I just figured you'd appreciate the comment since it seems you're learning :)

Comment: @JohnGibb I see. I just wrote it hastily. (This doesn't offend, rather it's helpful.)